# Including file breaks php script

Tags: php, html

Whenever I include a certain file in my PHP script, it breaks the code and only loads the stylesheet. I'm not sure what might be causing this issue. Is it caused by dependencies? I'm not sure if PHP inherits values, etc.

search.php calls a function in tablegen.php.

```
include 'tablegen.php';
```

tablegen.php creates a variable, and returns it.

Now, I want to pass this variable into a function in email.php.
However, when I do this:

```
include 'email.php';
```

This breaks the php script in "tablegen.php" and only a blank page with the background loads.

Thanks for any insight on this issue.

Full search.php file.

```
       <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {
background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

th{
width: 150px;
text-align:center;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
background-color: #008080;
font-family: Helvetica;
}
td {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
font-family: Helvetica;
background-color: #FFFF00;
text-align:center;
}
body {
background-color:#1C2932;
}

h1 {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 24px;
color: #989898;
}

p {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 18px;
color: #989898;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include 'tablegen.php';
include 'email.php';
if (empty($_POST['term'])) {
header("location:landing.php");
}
if(isset ($_POST['term'])) {
$x = $_POST['term'];
     connect();
     $result=tableGen($x);

}//end main if



echo "<form action='search.php' method = 'post'>";
echo "<p><b>Do you want this in an email?</b></p>";
echo "<input type='text' name='send'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send!' />";
echo "</form>";
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
sendEmail($result);
}

?>
<br></br>
<form method="LINK" action="landing.php">
<input type="submit" value="Go Back!">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Full tablegen.php file

```
<?php
include 'email.php';
function connect(){

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","water123") or die ('Error Reaching Database');
    mysql_select_db("MathGuide");


}   
    //Area  51, idk what I'm doing

function tableGen($x) {
$term=$x;
$sql = mysql_query("select * from student_info where ID like '$term'");
$output = "";
$output .= "<h1>STUDENT DATA for ID: $term</h1>";
$output .=  "<table>";
$output .=  "<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Starter Project</th>
<th>Course</th>
<th>KDs Completed in your Course</th>
<th>Projects Completed</th>
<th>Project 1</th>
<th>P1KD1</th>
<th>P1KD2</th>
<th>P1KD3</th>
<th>P1KD4</th>
<th>P1KD5</th>
<th>Project 2</th>
<th>P2KD1</th>
<th>P2KD2</th>
<th>P2KD3</th>
<th>P2KD4</th>
<th>P2KD5</th>
<th>Project 3</th>
<th>P3KD1</th>
<th>P3KD2</th>
<th>P3KD3</th>
<th>P3KD4</th>
<th>P3KD5</th>
<th>Project 4</th>
<th>P4KD1</th>
<th>P4KD2</th>
<th>P4KD3</th>
<th>P4KD4</th>
<th>P4KD5</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$output .=  "<tr><td>";
$output .=  $row['ID'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Starter Project'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Course'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['KDs completed in your course'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Projects Completed'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 1 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 2 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 3 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['Project 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 1'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 2'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 3'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 4'];
$output .=  "</td><td>";
$output .=  $row['P 4 KD 5'];
$output .=  "</td></tr>";

}
$output .=  "</table>";
sendEmail($output);
echo $output;
return $output;


}
error_reporting(-1); // display all faires
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  // ensure that faires will be seen
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); // display faires that didn't born

?>
```

Full email.php file:

```
  <html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color:#1C2932;
}
p {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 18px;
color: #989898;
}

</style>
</head>
 <body>
<?php
function sendEmail($table){
$email = $_POST['send'];
$headers = array(
'From: summitmathguide@gmail.com',
'Content-Type: text/html',
'Content-Type: text/css'
);
$content = $table;

mail($email,'HTML Email',$content,implode("\r\n",$headers));
echo "<p>Email Sent!</p>";
}
error_reporting(-1); // display all faires
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  // ensure that faires will be seen
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); // display faires that didn't born
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we see each scripts ?

Comment: Including a file is just basically inserting the contents of that file directly in the original script.

Comment: How did you arrive on your assumptions? How do you know that including email.php breaks script in tablegen.php?

Comment: I used Google Chrome's debugging feature and it gave me an error 500 for POST. I will put up the code right now.

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to get access to the functions in another file, isn't this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I'ts caused by `Evil Faires`, they are also called `Exceptions`, `Warnings` and `Fatal Errors`. They are invisible(so you can't see, yes, can't see!!!), you need to use some magical enviroment for be able to see these faires, so:

```
error_reporting(-1); // display all faires
ini_set('display_errors', 1);  // ensure that faires will be seen
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); // display faires that didn't born
```

Comment: Thanks! for the answer, I've updated my code above. And also, by using your code, I was able to get this output:  Notice: Undefined index: send in /var/www/email.php on line 17 However, the code for the post seems to be fine? Any insight would help.

Comment: You need to put it at the begining of `search.php`

Comment: Hi! I did this, and the code executed with no errors. However, when I added "sendEmail($output)" in search.php, I got this error: Notice: Undefined variable: output in /var/www/search.php on line 55

Notice: Undefined index: send in /var/www/email.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

This answer relates to the comment posted in response to I Am Not Procrastinating, not the code that is in the question at the moment (when you have a question about your code, you should post the version that contains the problem).

`$output` is a local variable inside the `tableGen()` function. You can't access it outside the function (unless you declare it with `global`, but there's no reason to do that in this case). The function ends with:

```
return $output
```

This means you can assign the result of the function call to a variable in `search.php`, e.g.

```
$result = tableGen($x);
sendEmail($output);
```

None of this has anything to do with using `include`, you would have the same problem if all the functions were in the main `search.php` file. Variable scope is based on classes and functions, not files.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I'm not getting any errors now, but I'm having trouble passing $result, into sendEmail(). When I enter the email and click the button that says "Send Email", it just goes to a blank "email.php" page. I see no errors displayed, and there aren't any errors in Chrome either. It should have an echo of "Email Sent."

Comment: You don't have a `<body>` tag after `</head>`.

Comment: Added them, still the same issue.

Comment: You have two different Content-Type headers in the email, but I don't think that should cause this. Is the mail being sent?

Comment: Yes it is going to be sent from an SMTP server.

Comment: I was able to send emails from this file, with a string message. This was before I started worrying about sending a variable to it.

Comment: The `sendEmail()` function is defined in `email.php` and called in `search.php`. But the form's action is `email.php`, so submitting the form doesn't run the code in `search.php`, so `sendEmail()` is never called.

Comment: So, is there a way to set a function as a "form action"? Does this mean I don't need the form isset?

Comment: The form action runs a script, and the script looks at the parameters and runs functions. You need to point to the script that does what you want at the top level. Include files are not usually meant to be run directly from form actions. You can use `action="search.php"`, and the search script can check whether `$_POST['send']` is set -- if it's set, it sends the email, otherwise it displays the form.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I've updated the code on the top. It looks like it should work. However, when I enter my email, it sends the email, but it is empty. Additionally, it redirects to the previous page, that calls search.php through a post.

Comment: It may be time for you to start sprinkling `var_dump()` statements through your code to see where the message is being lost. And it's supposed to go to search.php, that's what the action attribute does; if you want to go somewhere else, use a different action, or have the script send a redirect with `header("Location: someurl")`. Another thing: you call `sendEmail()` inside `tableGen()`, so you're sending the email twice. I don't see why the mail is empty, though.

Comment: I've removed sendEmail inside tableGen, sorry, I forgot to update the code. What does var_dump() do exactly? Strange why the message is empty. Could it be the headers not reading the html/css?

Comment: `var_dump()` displays the contents of variables in structured form, it's a basic tool in PHP debugging.

Comment: Something strange. Using the Google Chrome debugging tools. The POST is sent from search.php, and for some reason it redirects to "landing.php", which GETS it. I want "email.php" to GET it. IF you want, you can see the code for landing.php, which sends the value to search to "search.php".

Comment: You've changed `$_POST['send']` to `$_POST['term']`, but there's no field with that name in the form. As a result, the `header("location:landing.php");` code runs.

Comment: I've got to get back to my real work, I can't keep walking you through this. Every time you touch the script, you break it in a new way. You don't seem to know what you're doing at all.